# Faster zlib alternatives

Tags: performance, gzip, compression

I wonder, if there are any faster builds of zlib around with more advanced optimizations?

If it's possible to optimize it using SSE instructions or Intel C++ compiller, or some trick which were patented earlier (I know patents were a serious limitation during gzip/zlib development), have anyone bothered to implement that?

I am especially interested in compression speed, which have a direct impact on high-performance web-services serving static & dynamic content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several years after this question was first asked some faster x86_64 zlib's appeared using the type of optimization BarsMonster suggested:

- [Cloudflare zlib](https://github.com/cloudflare/zlib)
- [Intel zlib](https://github.com/jtkukunas/zlib)
- [Intel's igzip](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/igzip-a-high-performance-deflate-compressor-with-optimizations-for-genomic-data)
- [Google's c-zlib](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/zlib/)
- [libdeflate](https://github.com/ebiggers/libdeflate)

The authors of samtools (a suite of tools for interacting with high-throughput sequencing data) produced a [comparison of zlib speeds](http://www.htslib.org/benchmarks/zlib.html).

[zlib-ng collects zlib optimizations not in mainline zlib](https://github.com/Dead2/zlib-ng) but it may not be as stable as mainline zlib. Its issue tracker is also instructive as a reference to other known zlib speed ups.

Recently a [pull request that claims to "speed up inflate_fast by up to 1.5x on x86_64" (by filling and copying 8 bytes at a time)](https://github.com/madler/zlib/pull/292)  has been made but not accepted into mainline zlib. The patch providing this work is also having a bumpy ride being accepted into Chromium (see this [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=760853) and the [Chromium review](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/601694)) but hopefully the submitter will take a break to step away and recharge because from a distance it looks like progress was being very slowly made in a complex situation...

Even more recently, [libdeflate](https://github.com/ebiggers/libdeflate) is a heavily optimised rewrite that produces/confumes zlib compatible output/input but is does not provide a zlib compatible API. At the time of writing this has the zlib speed crown.

Comment: [Gildor2's fast zlib](https://github.com/gildor2/fast_zlib) too.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is the [miniz](http://code.google.com/p/miniz/) library (public domain, unlicense.org), which implements most of the zlib API in a single C source file and reads/writes zlib-compatible compressed data streams. At compression level 1 it uses a real-time compressor which is extremely fast (a little slower than minilzo, but with higher compression).

Answer (score 2):

Not a rebuild, but two good alternatives to zlib are quicklz and fastlz.  Both are very fast relative to gzip -1, but do not achieve as good of a compression ratio.  For my application, size was going up 10-15% but compression speed was 6x, so a very good tradeoff.

Of course neither is compatible with zlib, so it may not work for you.

Comment: Yes, I would need compatible one, for both API and algorithm.